# Zend Framework 2 email token verification

Tags: php, email, zend-framework2, token, verification

I am trying to make a system (in Zend Framework 2) to validate a user registration's email by sending an email with a link with a token (for example: http://example.com/user/autenticate/verify/abG12Fdss67j3kgfdds4jdpa74FiP9) so if the token is found in the database the pre-registered account moves to VERIFIED status.

I am using a route in module.config.php like this:

```
'verify' => array(
            'type'    => 'Segment',
            'options' => array(
                'route'    => '/user/autenticate/verify/:token',
                'defaults' => array(
                    '__NAMESPACE__' => 'User\Controller',
                    'controller'    => 'Autenticate',
                    'action'        => 'verify',
                ),
                    'constraints' => array(
                    'token' => '[a-zA-Z0-9]{30}'
                ),
            ),
        ),
```

then in AutenticateController.php, the following action method:

```
public function verifyAction()
{
    sleep(3); // Delay against brute attack (is it useful?)
    $token = $this->params()->fromRoute('token');
    $registerverification = new RegisterVerification();

    try {
        $registerverification = $this->getRegisterVerificationTable()->getRegisterVerification($token);

        // If arrives here (no exception) means that the token was in the database
        $aux = $this->getRegisterVerificationTable()->deleteRegisterVerification($token);
        $user = new User();
        $user = $this->getUserTable()->getUser((int)$registerverification->id);
        $user->verified = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
        $this->getUserTable()->saveUser($user);

        $this->flashMessenger()->addMessage("Now your account is active");
    } catch (\Exception $e) { // Could not find row: $token

        $this->flashMessenger()->addMessage($e->getMessage()); 
    }
    return array();
}
```

And a verify.phtml like this:

```
<?php
echo $this->flashMessenger()->render();
?>
```

**This is working, but not on the first attempt**, but only after refreshing the URL (http://example.com/user/autenticate/verify/abG12Fdss67j3kgfdds4jdpa74FiP9).

Can anyone help me on what do I have to do to make the method verifyAction() of AutenticateController.php being executed the first time the URL is called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The flash messenger is designed to show messages on the *next* request, so you probably want to redirect to another URL after adding your success message. That may be the only issue (otherwise please let us know what happens on the first request).

Comment: Wonderful @Tim! I created a new verifyanswerAction (with its view and its route) and just added a _return $this->redirect()->toRoute('verifyanswer');_ and the end of verifyAction instead of previous _return array();_ and it works fine.

Comment: By the way @Tim (I don't know if I can ask this here), do you think it is useful the _sleep(3);_ instruction at the beginning of  verifyAction() against a bot trying tokens?

Comment: You might want to move the sleep into your catch{} (so only people submitting invalid tokens are penalised).

Comment: But in that case, if the bot detects a delay in the answer, it can understand that is a mistaken token (and try with a new one) before waiting for the 3 seconds. My question was more in the sense that if the bot can try brute attacks without waiting for the server's answer (with a later procesing), or this is something detected by the hosting antihacking policies (assuming a good quality hosting, of course)

Comment: A bot can try multiple attacks at once - there isn't much you can do about that unless you want to start locking accounts after multiple failures. Personally I think what you have is fine.

Comment: Wonderfull @Tim, that is I was figuring. Thank you very much for your support. I would like to thank you with some karma-style feedback. I will search Stacoverflow for the way to do it. Best regards.